# I am using Axios to upload an image but server side doesn't get the request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**This is my client-side code. I'm using Axios here. I also use dropzone library to select images from internal drives. When I select an image using dropzone and press enter browser triggers the alert in the else part in below code.**

```
   function FileUpload(props) {

    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])

    const onDrop =(files)=> {
        let formData = new FormData();
        const config = {
            header:{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }
        formData.append('file', files[0])
        Axios.post('/product/uploadImage', formData, config)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.data.success) {
                setImages([...Images, response.data.image])
                props.refreshFunction([...Images, response.data.image])
            } else {
                alert('Failed to save the Image in Server')
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
            <Dropzone onDrop={onDrop} multiple={false} maxSize={800000000}>
                {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
                    <div style={{width:'300px', height:'240px', border:'1px solid lightgray', display:'flex', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}
                    {...getRootProps()}
                    >
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <Icon type="plus" style={{fontSize:'3rem'}}/>

                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**This is my server side code. I'm using multer to upload files.**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
},
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    if (ext !== '.jpg' || ext !== '.png') {
        return cb(res.status(400).end('only jpg, png are allowed'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true)
}
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single("file")

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send("Hello")
})

router.post('/uploadImage', (req, res) => {
upload(req, res, (err) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    if (err) return res.json({success: false, err})
    return res.json({success: true, image: res.req.file.path, fileName: res.req.file.filename})
})
});
```

Comment: What do the devtools say? Is the request made without errors (network tab), is there an error in the console and did you set up [proxy correctly](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)?

Comment: Make sure  path `'/product/uploadImage'` match at the backend. As I can see `/uploadImage` at backend router in your code or is it prefixed with `/product` that we don't see in code

Comment: I have define proxy correctly im getting     "success": false,
    "err": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "syscall": "open",
        "path": "D:\\Online-Fashion-Store\\server\\uploads\\1587221936515_dark-galaxy-stars-landsacpe-night-5k-26-3840x2160.jpg",
        "storageErrors": []
    }

Comment: seems like my formData object not passing to back-end